# You need to enable JavaScript to run this app - no API calls, no proxy

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend, npm-build

I created a sample React app using CRA. Created a simple component (just an `h1` element) and built the app for production using `npm run build.`

When I inspect `index.html` inside the `/build` folder, it has a line: `<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>`

This app doesn't make any API requests, hence no need for a proxy or anything related. Also, locally works fine.

Did anyone have such problems?

I’ve tried adding proxy in package.json even though **the app doesn’t have any API calls.**

Comment: The fact that you don't run any API calls doesn't implies that you don't run any JavaScript. If you're using React (a JavaScript library) then by definition you're using JavaScript.

Comment: @Alejandro what I wanted to do with that comment is to discourage comments regarding proxy. Just to keep us on the right track since a lot of questions regarding this are related to proxying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React applications are typically built as single-page applications (SPAs) that heavily rely on JavaScript to render and update the user interface dynamically. If JavaScript is disabled or not supported, the application will not function as expected because React relies on JavaScript to handle component rendering, state management, and interactions.

The  tag is used to provide a fallback for users who have disabled JavaScript or are using browsers that do not support it. It displays a message informing users that they need to enable JavaScript to use the application properly.

if JavaScript is disabled, the message inside the  tag will be displayed to the user. Otherwise, if JavaScript is enabled, the React application will be loaded and executed, rendering its components

Answer (score 0):

By default react does client side rendering using javascript to build HTML from your component definition. That is why the warning exists, without javascript enabled in the browser(it is on by default in most cases), the viewer would just get the info why it doesn't work.